# How do I make mercurial ignore symbolic links?

Tags: mercurial, symlink, hgignore

Can I add options to `.hgignore` or `.hgrc` such that symbolic links are automatically ignored in order to avoid clutter of `hg status`?

A solution like `find -type l  >> .hgignore` is infeasible as it tends to become slow, unmanageable and ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no options for ignoring certain types of files. The only thing you can match on it the filename.

People typically handle this by making sure that the files they want ignored follow a pattern so they can be matched with a glob or regex pattern — or they make sure that these files are in a common subdirectory and ignore that.